# Python web crawler download pic , pic format not be supported

Tags: python, image, format, web-crawler, cat

I was using same code to try to get cat's photo , the picture address is not different.

But why does one can get picture , other one can't be got?

```
#pic download successfully.
    import requests
    pic=requests.get('https://preview.redd.it/vf19rde7cwsa1.jpg?width=960&crop=smart&auto=webp&v=enabled&s=19a18f4a818e424d84cd2b5bf2c8fcaa02690fa0') 
    img2 = pic.content 
    pic_out = open('img123.png','wb') 
    pic_out.write(img2) 
    pic_out.close() 
#pic download successfully.




#pic format not be supported.
    import requests
    pic=requests.get('https://imgur.dcard.tw/N2k5kV2h.jpg') 
    img2 = pic.content 
    pic_out = open('img1.png','wb') 
    pic_out.write(img2) 
    pic_out.close()

#pic format not be supported.
```

Comment: @Ukeme Bos Wilson


Hi Wilson , thanks for your respond.
But I try to add your suggestion, that still can't get picture from url.


`import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36 '
}

pic = requests.get('https://imgur.dcard.tw/N2k5kV2h.jpg', headers=headers)
# pic=requests.get('https://imgur.dcard.tw/N2k5kV2h.jpg') 
img2 = pic.content 
pic_out = open('img1.png','wb') 
pic_out.write(img2) 
pic_out.close()`

Answer (score 0):

Requests is a powerful python tool, but however it cannot do everything. Especially if the content you are requesting is protected (e.g by cloudflare)

Looking at the status code of the second image you wanted returned an error 403 : **Forbidden**
[image]

Looking at the text of the picture showed that the host who you are requesting from is checking is checking out your request
[image]

That brings us to what is called **HEADERS**

You are able to see the image in your browser because your browser sends a Header to the host.

```
import requests
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36 '
}

result = requests.get(your_url, headers=headers)
```

In a lot of cases, this should do the trick.

Sadly , this particular image url is well protected.
So just skip and try another url

Comment: Hi Wilson , thanks for your respond.
But I try to add your suggestion, that still can't get picture from url.


`import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36 '
}

pic = requests.get('https://imgur.dcard.tw/N2k5kV2h.jpg', headers=headers)
# pic=requests.get('https://imgur.dcard.tw/N2k5kV2h.jpg') 
img2 = pic.content 
pic_out = open('img1.png','wb') 
pic_out.write(img2) 
pic_out.close()`

Comment: Yeah. Just like I said earlier. That particular url is protected. Requests cant touch it. You can try other Urls